# DOS Batch that sends email via outlook: need to add new lines

Tags: batch-file, outlook, dos, line-breaks, batch-processing

Here is part of my batch:

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m "email address&cc=email address 2;email address 3&subject=Very Important Alert&body=Line 1 of alert\nLine 2 of alert"
```

This is just inserting the literal `\n` into the body though. How do I get it to insert actual line breaks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
"...&body=Line 1 of alert\r\nLine 2 of alert"
```

Or this:

```
"...&body=Line 1 of alert%%0D%%0ALine 2 of alert"
```

Comment: This one worked for me: `%%0D%%0A`. `\r\n` Was still inserting literal `\r\n` sequences.

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me; however, I had to click on the <kbd>send</kbd> button to complete the process.

```
start "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office12\OUTLOOK.EXE" /c ipm.note /m "FromEmailAddress&cc=EmailAddress1;EmailAddress1&subject=Very Important Alert&body=Line 1 of alert%%0D%%0ALine 2 of alert"
```